# How to programmatically select a bound `NavigationViewItem` of `NavigationView` after binding is updated

Tags: c#, asynchronous, data-binding, uwp, windows-10

My setup is basically as follows:

- `NavigationView`'s `MenuItemsSource` is bound to `viewModel.NavItems`.

  - `NavItems` is a computed property of `viewModel`.
- The view model class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for binding purpose
- `Books` of view model is loaded **asynchronously**.

### What works

The `NavigationViewItem`s show up after the page is reached.

### The Problem

I need to set a specified `NavigationViewItem` as the  [`SelectedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.selecteditem#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_NavigationView_SelectedItem) of the `NavigationView`. But there's no `NavigationViewItem` (from `viewModel`) to use inside [`OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Page_OnNavigatedTo_Windows_UI_Xaml_Navigation_NavigationEventArgs_), because at that point `viewModel.NavItems` is not ready yet.

So **is there a pattern for selecting a `NavigationViewItem` in this async situation?**

#### XAML

```
<NavigationView x:Name="navView" 
                MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.NavItems, Mode=OneWay}"
                SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged" >
…
```

#### the view model

```
internal class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // The data service
        private MainDataService mainDataService = new MainDataService();

        private List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
        public List<Book> Books
        {
            get
            {
                return this.books;
            }
            set
            {
                this.books = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
                this.OnPropertyChanged("NavItems");
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<NavigationViewItemBase> NavItems
        {
            get
            {
                return Books.SelectMany(
                    b => (new List<NavigationViewItemBase> { new NavigationViewItemHeader {
                        Content = b.Title,
                        Tag = b.Title
                    } })
                    .Concat(
                        b.Sections.Select(s => new NavigationViewItem
                        {
                            Content = s.Title,
                            Icon = new FontIcon { Glyph = "\uE8B7", FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe MDL2 Assets") }
                        })
                    )
                );
            }
        }

        // @param selectedBookIndex: the index of the book whose first section
        // should be selected.
        public async Task UpdateBooks(int selectedBookIndex)
        {
            await mainDataService.PrepareData();
            this.Books = mainDataService.Books;
        }

        …
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> So is there a pattern for selecting a NavigationViewItem in this async situation?

For async situation, you need use [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) but not `List`. And it represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

> But there's no NavigationViewItem (from viewModel) to use inside OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e), because at that point viewModel.NavItems is not ready yet.

Before the data is not ready, you could keep the `Frame` navigation to the default page that used as placehoder within `NavigationView` Loaded event.
For more you could refer [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).